# Using bind instead of promises or stacked callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen tutorials about node promises and such but not using bind. I feel like I can do lots of things this way and keep everything clean:

```
Updater.prototype.generateLocFieldForDocs = function(docs) {
  console.log('list obtained')
  async.eachLimit(docs, 10, this.generateLocFieldForDoc.bind(this), this.generateLocFieldForDocsDone.bind(this))
}

Updater.prototype.generateLocFieldForDoc = function(doc, done) {
  this.collection.update({_id: doc._id},
  {$set: {
    loc: {...}
  }}, function(err, result) {
    this.errorHandler(err)
    done()
  }.bind(this))
}

Updater.prototype.generateLocFieldForDocsDone = function(err) {
  this.errorHandler(err)
  this.generateLocFieldNextSection()
}
```

What do you think about using classes and `bind` like this in node.js?

What `bind` does is that it's sets the `this` in the function body to the `this` passed to `bind` therefore keeping the context you want.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question: Asynchronous operations and context binding are orthogonal concepts. Asynchronous callbacks just happen to be a good use case for `bind`, but there are other ways of ensuring the correct context. I mean, the code looks fine; it's one solution among many. If you like it and it works, go with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've realized there's no need for all these prototype functions and binds.
When using node.js, in a file, the normal named functions are private to the file, so it can be used as methods.

```
var self = {
  parallelLimit: 10
}

function generateLocFieldForDocs(docs) {
  log('list obtained')
  async.eachLimit(docs, self.parallelLimit, generateLocFieldForDoc, generateLocFieldForDocsDone)
}

function generateLocFieldForDoc(doc, done) {
  self.collection.update({_id: doc._id},
  {$set: {
    loc: {...}
  }}, function(err, result) {
    errorHandler(err)
    done()
  })
}

function generateLocFieldForDocsDone(err) {
  errorHandler(err)
  generateLocFieldNextSection()
}
```

Using `module.export.myFunction =` makes it public